# RadWindow not opening on client

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, attributes, radwindow

I have a puzzling situation I need some help with here please. I am trying to cause my button to open a RadWindow( Another page in a PopUp), and I would appreciate any help I can get with this please.

I have a simple button on my form (A UserControl Form). What I would like to do is pop open a RadWindow when the button is clicked . What currently happens is a window opens and then closes, almost immediately.

I have the code below in my code behind

```
    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        BtnGenerateReport.Attributes("onclick") = " return GenerateSelectedReport('" & intPrimaryKey & "');"
    End Sub
```

And on the client side, I have

```
  function GenerateSelectedReport(reportid) {
       var wlink = "Popuppage.aspx?intRptKey=" + reportid
       window.radopen(wlink, "REPORT GENERATOR");
       oWnd.center();
       return true;
   }
```

Comment: Can you tell use more about the code behind the window page? Is there any code in any of the Page events such as Load or Init? Is there any script being injected when the Window page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you returning "true" in GenerateSelectedReport?  Try changing it to false and see what happens.

The problem is occuring because the button is causing a postback that you need to cancel.  Returning false will cancel the button action after the Javascript has run.

Comment: @Kobojunkie: Is there anything that needs to be added to this answer before you can accept?  Did it not help to solve your issue?

Comment: I am sorry, for the late response. I did change that bit to false but that did not solve the problem at all. I added alert() flags but it seems the function is not being called at all

Comment: Also, I did check for postbacks, and that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Why are you attaching the onclick method in the page_init event?  If you move this to the page_load event, does any change occur?  Also, do a quick "view source" on the page and make sure that the onclick method is in fact being attached to btnGenerateReport.

Comment: ya i would move that to the page_load, the control might not be initialized yet in the page_init.  worth a try for sure

Comment: @jonezy: Yeah, it doesn't make sense to have that code running in the page_init.  The OP might have a reason for doing so but, right now, it can't see why.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/radwindow-opens-and-then-immediately-closes.aspx) the return false statement should be inline with the call to the function like so

```
orderMaintenanceOpenWindow(); return false;
```

So try removing the return false; from your js method and update your call to this:

```
BtnGenerateReport.Attributes("onclick") = " GenerateSelectedReport('" & intPrimaryKey & "'); return false;"
```